# Convert a function from Python to TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert the [R3Det](https://github.com/Thinklab-SJTU/R3Det_Tensorflow.git) Model that outputs rotated bounding boxes to a TensorFlow Lite model for on device inference on mobile devices. The problem that I am facing is that a part of the inference model uses python code wrapped by `tf.py_func` which is not serializable. I am trying to convert the function to TensorFlow but it contains a `for` loop and some OpenCV funtion calls, and I have no idea how to convert these into TensorFlow code. I would appreciate it, if anybody can help me out with this. The python function is given below.

```py
def nms_rotate_cpu(boxes, scores, iou_threshold, max_output_size):

    """
    :param boxes: format [x_c, y_c, w, h, theta]
    :param scores: scores of boxes
    :param threshold: iou threshold (0.7 or 0.5)
    :param max_output_size: max number of output
    :return: the remaining index of boxes
    """

    keep = []

    order = scores.argsort()[::-1]
    num = boxes.shape[0]

    suppressed = np.zeros((num), dtype=np.int)

    for _i in range(num):
        if len(keep) >= max_output_size:
            break

        i = order[_i]
        if suppressed[i] == 1:
            continue
        keep.append(i)
        r1 = ((boxes[i, 0], boxes[i, 1]), (boxes[i, 2], boxes[i, 3]), boxes[i, 4])
        area_r1 = boxes[i, 2] * boxes[i, 3]
        for _j in range(_i + 1, num):
            j = order[_j]
            if suppressed[i] == 1:
                continue

            if np.sqrt((boxes[i, 0] - boxes[j, 0])**2 + (boxes[i, 1] - boxes[j, 1])**2) > (boxes[i, 2] + boxes[j, 2] + boxes[i, 3] + boxes[j, 3]):
                inter = 0.0
            else:

                r2 = ((boxes[j, 0], boxes[j, 1]), (boxes[j, 2], boxes[j, 3]), boxes[j, 4])
                area_r2 = boxes[j, 2] * boxes[j, 3]
                inter = 0.0

                try:
                    int_pts = cv2.rotatedRectangleIntersection(r1, r2)[1]

                    if int_pts is not None:
                        order_pts = cv2.convexHull(int_pts, returnPoints=True)

                        int_area = cv2.contourArea(order_pts)

                        inter = int_area * 1.0 / (area_r1 + area_r2 - int_area + cfgs.EPSILON)

                except:
                    """
                      cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/intersection.cpp:247:
                      error: (-215) intersection.size() <= 8 in function rotatedRectangleIntersection
                    """
                    # print(r1)
                    # print(r2)
                    inter = 0.9999

            if inter >= iou_threshold:
                suppressed[j] = 1

    return np.array(keep, np.int64)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's possible to call OpenCV functions from within TensorFlow code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456567/how-to-call-opencv-functions-in-tensorflowpython/54458291 seems discouraging on that front.

Comment: I've tested this code and it works, so I think it is possible to use opencv functions using Tensorflow's py_func. However, I am not sure about the derivative which is referred to in your mention question but I guess since I can train the model that works as well. For my case I was thinking about rewriting the OpenCV algos in TF.